# Is it possible to override a type's existing Debug implementation?

Tags: logging, rust

I have typedef for a `HashMap`:

```
pub type Linear = HashMap<i16, f64>;

impl fmt::Debug for Linear {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
      // write!...
    }
}
```

I want custom printing for it, but it doesn't want to compile. Is it possible to override it without making a wrapper?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is it possible to override it without making a wrapper?

No, you need to make the wrapper. Remember that type aliases **do not create new types** — that's why they are called *aliases*. If you were able to redefine `Debug` here, you'd be affecting *every* `HashMap` (not a good idea).

You only need the wrapper when printing, so you could have `println!("{:?}", DebugWrapper(&a_linear_value))`.

---

You could be exceedingly fancy and make an extension trait to do the same thing:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::fmt;

pub type Linear = HashMap<i16, f64>;

trait MyDebug<'a> {
    type Debug: 'a;

    fn my_debug(self) -> Self::Debug;
}

impl<'a> MyDebug<'a> for &'a Linear {
    type Debug = LinearDebug<'a>;

    fn my_debug(self) -> Self::Debug { LinearDebug(self) }
}

struct LinearDebug<'a>(&'a Linear);

impl<'a> fmt::Debug for LinearDebug<'a> {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "custom")
    }
}

fn main() {
    let l = Linear::new();
    println!("{:?}", l);
    println!("{:?}", l.my_debug());
}
```